# Loop not working in the spinner

Tags: android, loops, textview, spinner

I have implemented the following method

```
public class mainpage extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener{
private Spinner spinner;
private ArrayList<String> albay;
private JSONArray result;
TextView textViewLocation1;
TextView textViewLocation2;
TextView textViewType_route;
TextView textViewStart_date;
TextView textViewEnd_date;
TextView textViewDate;
TextView textViewInfo;
```

Whenever I put "spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);" my app crashes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);
    albay = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    getData();
```

As for as I code, I think my problem is on the loop cycle

```
    private void getDate(JSONArray j){
    for (int i=0;i<j.length();i++){
try {
    JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
    albay.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_DATE));
}catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpage.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, albay));
    }
```

The log says error is on "**textViewLocation1.setText(getlocation1(position));**". But the spinner havs the data from the database.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item
    textViewLocation1.setText(getlocation1(position));
    textViewLocation2.setText(getlocation2(position));
    textViewType_route.setText(gettype_route(position));
    textViewStart_date.setText(getstart_date(position));
    textViewEnd_date.setText(getend_date(position));
    textViewDate.setText(get_date(position));
    textViewInfo.setText(getinfo(position));
}

//When no item is selected this method would execute
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    textViewLocation1.setText("?");
    textViewLocation2.setText("?");
    textViewType_route.setText("?");
    textViewStart_date.setText("?");
    textViewEnd_date.setText("?");
    textViewDate.setText("?");
    textViewInfo.setText("?");
}
```

This is the logcat says, the "179" is the "**textViewLocation1.setText(getlocation1(position));**"

```
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa43d06c0, tid 5038
02-17 14:46:13.932 4359-4359/com.example.locator.albay E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.locator.albay, PID: 4359
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.example.locator.albay.mainpage.onItemSelected(mainpage.java:179)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
02-17 14:46:14.731 1308-1308/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1308: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
02-17 14:46:15.557 1875-2409/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 104)
02-17 14:46:15.586 1875-2409/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 108)
02-17 14:46:15.617 1875-1956/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '2cd2106 com.example.locator.albay/com.example.locator.albay.mainpage (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: Please post your logcat. Probably the variable textViewLocation1 is null. How are you binding it?

Comment: Show your logcat for error

Comment: I added now the logcat. Sorry for the delay, my pc freezed and I'm new in Android.

Comment: where is your findviewId for textViewLocation1?

Comment: Ohh! I forgot to add that! Thank you very much! :)) I need to be more careful next time!